# sum two integer numbers in tcsh script

Tags: shell, scripting, tcsh

I want to sum two integers in `tcsh`. I have seen how to do this in bash. 
One variable is set by the queue manager, the other variable is a constant variable hardcoded in the script.
I have tried

```
setenv II 199
setenv AA 1
echo $((${II}+${AA}))
```

but `illegal variable name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer arithmetic in tcsh can be done in expressions taken by the assignment command "`@`":

```
@ num1 = 3
@ num2 = 10
echo $num1
echo $num2

@ res=$num1 + $num2
echo "num1 + num2 = $res"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setenv II 199
setenv AA 1
@ res = $II + $AA
echo $res
```

advice: csh parser had few bugs, use spaces where it must especially in arithmetics expressions between operators and numbers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just post lines of code is definitely not a good answer. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).